# Respawning a node after it's been deleted? Swift Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Once a node is removed, I'm needing to respawn it back to it's original position.

I've tried a few things:

1) In the `didBeginContact` where it gets deleted, I've just added an `addChild()` after the delete, but that just added it back where it was, making it look like it just paused in place

2) When it dies, I'm setting a variable to 0, and I created a function that adds the node back where it starts out, and then I set up an if statement that looks like :

```
if playerLife == 0 {
    spawnPlayer()
}
```

and the player life gets set to 0 down in my `didBeginContact`. Don't know if that even makes sense

3) I tried slapping all of this down in the `didBeginContact`

The ball is either freezing when I try to addchild directly back right after I delete it in the DidBegin, otherwise it gets deleted and never is respawned.

Comment: With your first appempt you just needed to reset the position of the node back to it's original position. Then it should have worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your code inside of the update function. also in your spawnPlayer function make sure to add your node if node.parent == nil

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    if playerLife == 0 {
        spawnPlayer()
    }
}
```